# generate a matrix of possible combinations using fortran

Tags: fortran

I have an array X(9,2) and I want to generate another array B(512,9) with all the possible combinations.

I thought about doing 9 do loops, but I was hoping for a more efficient way.

This is what I have

```
    do i1=1, 2
    do i2=1, 2
        do i3=1,2
            do i4=1,2
                do i5=1,2
                    do i6=1,2
                        do i7=1,2
                            do i8=i,2
                                do i9=1,2
                                    B(row, col) = X(1,i1)
                                    col = col + 1
                                    B(row, col) = X(2,i2)
                                    col = col + 1
                                    B(row, col) = X(3,i3)
                                    col = col + 1
                                    B(row, col) = X(4,i4)
                                    col = col + 1
                                    B(row, col) = X(5,i5)
                                    col = col + 1
                                    B(row, col) = X(6,i6)
                                    col = col + 1
                                    B(row, col) = X(7,i7)
                                    col = col + 1
                                    B(row, col) = X(8,i8)
                                    col = col + 1
                                    B(row, col) = X(9,i9)
                                    col = 1
                                    row = row + 1
                                end do
                            end do
                        end do
                    end do
                end do
            end do
        end do
    end do
end do
```

Is there something wrong with this way? Is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make the loops the other way around by looping over the elements of B like the following (I have a print statement instead of the assignment...):

```
 program test
  implicit none

  integer, parameter :: nn = 9, imax = 2
  integer :: row, col, ii
  integer :: indices(nn)

  indices(:) = 1
  do row = 1, imax**nn
    do col = 1, nn
      print "(A,I0,A,I0,A,I0,A,I0,A)", "B(", row, ",", col, ") = X(",&
          & col, ",", indices(col), ")"
      !B(row, col) = X(col, indices(col))
    end do
    indices(nn) = indices(nn) + 1
    ii = nn
    do while (ii > 1 .and. indices(ii) > imax)
      indices(ii) = 1
      indices(ii-1) = indices(ii-1) + 1
      ii = ii - 1
    end do
  end do

end program test
```

As far as I can see, this gives the same result as your original code, but is by far more compact and works for any tuple sizes and index ranges.

Answer (score 1):

I think this does the trick too

```
ncol = 9
B = 0
tot = 2**ncol
do n = 1, ncol
   div = 2**n
   step = tot/div
   do m = 0, div-1
      fr = 1 + m*step
      to = fr + step
      B(fr:to,n) = X(n, 1+mod(m,2))
   end do
end do

do n = 1, tot
     write(*,*) (B(n,i), i=1,ncol)
end do
```

Answer (score 0):

There is indeed a better way. See, for instance, [Martin Broadhurst's combinatorial algorithms](http://www.martinbroadhurst.com/combinatorial-algorithms.html) -- in particular the cartesian product example and the file `n-tuple.c`. Despite being in C, the code uses arrays and reference parameters throughout and so could be translated to Fortran without any difficulty other than changing the indices to start at 1 rather than 0. The approach he uses is to count upwards with an index array.

Comment: Thanks Simon! I don't know c, any change of getting some fortran code?

Comment: I haven't come across any code in Fortran that would be suitable. The translation from C wouldn't be at all difficult, though. You'd need to change the `for` loop into a `while` loop and the `++` operators from `x++` into `x=x+1` etc. but otherwise the Fortran subroutine would look very much like the C. You could almost do it by trying to compile the C with a Fortran compiler and just fixing the syntax errors that the compiler reports one-by-one. You can find a good introductory (and quick) guide to C for Fortran programmers [here](http://drum.lib.umd.edu/bitstream/1903/8434/1/CPP.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

```
  character *70 ofil
  ofil='allcomb.txt'
  write(*,*)'feed n and m (Note: n or m larger than 20 takes time)'
  read(*,*) n,m
  write(*,*)'feed file name to store results'
  read(*,*) ofil
  call combin(n,m,ofil)
  write(*,*)'Over'
  end
  !---------------------------------------------------------------
  subroutine combin(n,m,ofil)
  ! Generates all ncm combinatins
  parameter (mx=20)! mx is maximum dimension
  Integer a(mx),b(mx),c
  double precision ncm,ic
  character *70 ofil
  open(15,file=ofil)
  ncm=1
    do i=1,m
    a(i)=i ! a is least indexed combination
    b(i)=n-m+i ! b is maximum indexed combination
    ncm=ncm*b(i)/i ! total possible combinations
    enddo
  write (15,*) (a(i),i=1,m)! Initial (least indexed) combination
  incmpl=1
  ic=1
  ! --------------------------------------------------------------
  do while (incmpl.ne.0 .and.int(ic).lt.ncm)
  incm=0
    do i=1,m
    incm=incm+(b(i)-a(i))
    enddo
  incmpl=incm
  a(m)=a(m)+1
    do i=1,m
    ii=m-i+1
      if(a(ii).gt.b(ii)) then
      a(ii-1)=a(ii-1)+1
         do j=ii,m
         a(j)=a(j-1)+1
         enddo
      endif
    enddo
  ic=ic+1
  write(15,*)(a(k),k=1,m)
  enddo ! end do while loop
  ! --------------------------------------------------------------
  close(15)
  return
  end
```

Comment: Welcome. It is always good to explain your code. Code only answers are frowned upon especially if they are more then a couple of lines. I know there are other answers here which do not explain too much, but they are old and don't have many upvotes.